# Setting local image as EaselJS background

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, easeljs, createjs

I am building an EaselJS app, and I want the user to be able to select an image from their hard drive to be the background for the app. Once they are done interacting with the app and choose to submit I want to upload the image, but not before then. Is there a way I can do this? I am using Rails if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [readAsDataURL from Filereader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL),then pass the result to an Image object and finally pass that image as parameter of a new easeljs.Bitmap object.

```
function previewFile(){
    var file = input.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        image.src = reader.result;
        var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
        stage.addChild(bitmap);
    }
    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        alert("fail");
    }
}
```

I created a fiddle that does something like that:
https://jsfiddle.net/vampaynani/b5maj7nd/